# How can I set Material Drawer width to the width of its children in Reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, drawer

I'm using Material-ui Drawer to hide/show content on the right side of the screen. When Drawer is open, it should shrinks the content in the right (no overlapping). I'm setting the drawer width value from a variable and it is working fine. However, I need to replace the value of that variable with whatever width value its child ()component has.

This is the code with the Drawer component:

```js
import { useState } from "react";

// Material UI components
import { Box, Button, Drawer, Divider, Grid, IconButton } from "@mui/material";

// Components
import DashboardHeader from "./DashboardHeader/DashboardHeader";
import LeadershipProfile from "./LeadershipProfile/LeadershipProfile";
import YourProfile from "./YourProfile/YourProfile";
import CustomIcon from "components/CustomIcon";
import icons from "enums/icons";

import { Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import makeStyles from "@mui/styles/makeStyles";
import createStyles from "@mui/styles/createStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        leftSideContainer: {
            display: "contents",
            overflow: "auto",
            textAlign: "center",
        },
        drawer: {
            top: theme.spacing(9),
            "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
                // width: "30%",
                marginTop: "72px",
                position: "absolute",
            },
        },
        drawerButton: {
            color: theme.palette.button.active.from,
            height: "14px",
        },
        // divider: {
        //     "& .MuiDivider-root": {
        //         right: 0,
        //     },
        // },
    })
);

const PaceLabsDashboard = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const [isDrawerOpen, setIsDrawerOpen] = useState(true);
    const drawerContentWidth = 400;

    return (
        <Box>
            {/* Header */}
            <Box sx={{ border: "2px solid black", width: "100%", height: "72px", textAlign: "center" }}>
                <DashboardHeader />
            </Box>

            <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
                {/* Right content */}
                <Box className={classes.leftSideContainer}>
                    {/* <Box textAlign="center"> */}
                    <LeadershipProfile />
                    {/* </Box> */}

                    {/* <Divider className={classes.divider} orientation="vertical"> */}
                    <IconButton size="small" aria-label="toggle-drawer" onClick={() => setIsDrawerOpen(!isDrawerOpen)}>
                        <CustomIcon
                            className={classes.drawerButton}
                            icon={isDrawerOpen ? icons.chevronRightThin : icons.chevronLeftThin}
                        />
                    </IconButton>
                    {/* </Divider> */}
                </Box>

                {/* Left content */}
                <Drawer
                    anchor="right"
                    variant="persistent"
                    open={isDrawerOpen}
                    className={classes.drawer}
                    sx={{
                    ...(isDrawerOpen ? { display: "flex" } : { display: { xs: "block", sm: "none" } }),
                }}
                >
                    <Box>
                        <YourProfile />
                    </Box>
                </Drawer>
            </Box>
        </Box>
    );
};

export default PaceLabsDashboard;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sx={{
  display: { xs: "block", sm: "none" },
  "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
    boxSizing: "border-box",
    width: drawerWidth
  }
}}
```

Comment: Ok, I edited the code in the question and I replaced the sx part inside the Drawer, so now I don't have to set the drawer width into a variable and the drawer width is whatever the width of the Drawer's child (<YourProfile />). However, I found that this makes the drawer to overlaps the content on the left side, and because of that, the arrow button that handles the open/close remains hidden. I need the left content to shrinks when the Drawer is open so all the content in the left side remains visible.